# encode string width quotes to UTF-8 in php

Tags: php, html, utf

How to convert string with quotes, for example:

```
#1050;&#1086;&#1084;&#1087;&#1083;&#1077;&#1082;&#1090
```

to UTF-8. I want to add it to db, methods such as `utf8_decode()` doesn't work. Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: How you are doing to convert this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it

```
html_entity_decode("#1050;&#1086;&#1084;&#1087;&#1083;&#1077;&#1082;&#1090", ENT_QUOTES,  
'UTF-8');
```